# Typescript 0.9.5 compilation with var args fails

Tags: jquery, typescript

So im trying to upgrade to typescript 0.9.5 in our project, but im currently stuck.

This is the error im reciving from the compiler:

```
error TS2082: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
Call signatures of types '(event: JQueryEventObject, component: any,
     mouseClickPagePosition: any) => void' and 
    '(eventObject: JQueryEventObject, ...args: any[]) => any' are incompatible:
                Call signature expects 1 or fewer parameters.
```

It seems like this code:

```
jQuery('selector').on('event',
            (event, component, mouseClickPagePosition) => {
              // code
            });
```

cannot be used with this jQuery definition:

```
on(events: string, handler: (eventObject: JQueryEventObject, ...args: any[]) => any): JQuery;
```

But the method signatures seems to add up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code

```
jQuery('selector').on('event',
            (event, component, mouseClickPagePosition) => {
              // code
            });
```

should be written as this instead:

```
jQuery('selector').on('event',
            (event, component?, mouseClickPagePosition?) => {
              // code
            });
```

The callback on `on` specifies that it will be called with at least one parameter, and *possibly* more. The callback provided *required* three parameters, so it's considered an error.

This code was only accidently allowed pre-0.9.5, but given how annoying/unintuitive this is, it's being considered as a design change to allow these parameters to be 'required' instead of optional.

Comment: Makes sense now that you say it... Thanks!